# JPA @Transient Value being recalled

Tags: jpa, transient

I have an entity `Ticket.class` that has the following properties (amongst others):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Comment> comments;

@Transient
private Comment comment;
```

I then have a method as follows:

```
public void edit() {
    ...
    // Add the comment
    comments.add(comment);
    comment = new Comment();

    // Persist the ticket
    em.merge(ticket);
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I next retrieve the `Ticket` from the DB the `@Transient` value is present and set to the last comment. This must be coming from a cache but I can't figure out where or how to flush it other than by restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you flush your entity before merge. try

```
 em.flush()
```

there might be possiblity that entity has not sysnchronize with database.